# How Do I know the current cocos2d version within my project?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I do have the 3.0 version template installed which is displayed in the xcode new project wizard, however I have an old project which is not 3.0 but I have to idea which version it is.

any help?

Comment: besides Oliviers answer you can also just run the app and look at the log, the version number is typically printed in the first bunch of log lines

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your file cocos2d.h the first define is the version number:

```
#define COCOS2D_VERSION 0x00010001 => 1.01

#define COCOS2D_VERSION 0x00020200 => 2.2
```

In your file cocos2d.m the first const is a string with your version too:

```
const char *cocos2d_version = "cocos2d-iphone v2.2";
```